# Rock-Paper-Scissors game in JavaScript. Infinite loop issue

Tags: javascript, function, infinite-loop

I am learning JavaScript through The Odin Project and currently stucked with the Rock-Paper-Scissors exercise. Program below works properly at a single round but when I add a **for loop** to the **game()** function to call **playRound()** for five times and keep score it gives an **infinite loop error** for the line where **for loop** is.

The program could be configured differently but this is what the project requests. Any help is appreciated.

```js
  
//random choice generator
  
  function computerPlay() {

    function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    let number = getRandomArbitrary(0, 3)
    if (number == 0) {
      return 'ROCK'
    } else if (number == 1) {
      return 'PAPER'
    } else {
      return 'SCISSORS'
    }
  }


  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Single Round Main

  function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {


    playerSelection = playerSelection.toUpperCase()


    if (computerSelection == playerSelection) {
      console.log('DEUCE')
      return 0
    } else if ((playerSelection == 'ROCK' && computerSelection == 'SCISSORS') || (playerSelection == 'PAPER' &&
        computerSelection == 'ROCK') || (playerSelection == 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection == 'PAPER')) {
      console.log('You Win! ' + playerSelection + ' beats ' + computerSelection + '.')
      return 1
    } else if ((playerSelection == 'SCISSORS' && computerSelection == 'ROCK') || (playerSelection == 'ROCK' &&
        computerSelection == 'PAPER') || (playerSelection == 'PAPER' && computerSelection == 'SCISSORS')) {
      console.log('You Lose! ' + computerSelection + ' beats ' + playerSelection + '.')
      return 0
    }
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  
  function game() {

    let score = 0

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let computerSelection = computerPlay()
      let playerSelection = prompt('Choose one! Rock, Paper or Scissors.')
      let result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)


      if (result == 1) {
        score += 1
      } else {
        score += 0
      }
    }
    console.log(score)
  }


  game()
```

Comment: You should be defining the variables in your for loop - `for (let i = 0; ....`

Comment: Can you add the code for how you're playing 5 games?

Comment: It's in the game() function below the code area. The for loop.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming there would be an extra one - in that case I can't replicate it

Comment: This *works*. Weirdly, it's being detected as a potential infinite loop. Weird, not sure why this is the case. Seems to be related to the alert functionality.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, it works for one round and then gives an error.

Comment: Runs fine for me (in chrome version 79.0.3945.88)

Comment: Well, i just now tried the "run code snippet"  feature in this page and it worked, then tried it at "repl.it" and it worked properly at there too. I had been using "playcode.io" to test and it was giving the error. Maybe there is something wrong with the "playcode.io".

Comment: [I posted a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523031/could-using-native-browser-modal-dialogs-in-a-loop-lead-to-potentially-infinite). It appears that for some reason having a modal dialog is being detected as "potentially infinite loop". Happens on JSBin but I guess the platform you're using either employs the same algorithm for analysing the code or might actually be using JSBin for the execution. At any rate, I don't know *why* this is being detected as "potentially infinite". It's either a mistake or there is an actual problem.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh ok, I understand. Thanks for help.

Comment: So, turns out the analysis is much simpler than I thought. The loop just takes "too much time". On JSBin the loop will get terminated if it takes more than 100ms. And since `prompt` will wait for user input and it takes longer than the timeout, it gets wrongly detected as "potentially infinite".

Comment: It seems sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried the "run code snippet"  feature in this page just now and it worked properly, then tried it at "repl.it" and it worked properly at there too. I had been using "playcode.io" to test the code and it was giving the error. Maybe there is something wrong with the "playcode.io".

So, i think it works.