# Why does this JS prompt terminate the while loop it is inside of?

Tags: javascript, loops, break, prompt

This while loop will only iterate once when run. If I replace `prompt("Enter anything")` with a value, the loop functions properly. How can I use a prompt with a while loop and prevent it from breaking the loop?

```js
var c = 0
while (c < 3) {
  var p = prompt("Enter anything")
  console.log([c, p])
  c++
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet works just fine.

Comment: When I run it, it works fine, prompting 3 times.

Comment: In the snippet the loop does continue as expected. It just stops while you are filling out the prompt since prompt & alert stop all javascript from being processed when they are open.

Comment: I think what Uncle Slug means is that the console.log()s happen only after the third prompt finished

Comment: Are you [seeing a only a single iteration on JSBin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59523031)?

Comment: @VLAZ yes, only a single iteration on JSBin

Comment: @VLAZ yes! Adding ```// noprotect``` after the prompt worked